# How to read one .zip file from apk in android Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I want to Download one .zip file from apk file to my sdcard in android titanium.

I have placed my .zip file on Project/Resources/android folder.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to unzip the file?
There are a quiet a few zip modules you can use: http://gitt.io/search?q=zip

and one from Appc: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.compression/tree/master/android

Have a look at the example folder and the dist folder for the module.

Comment: Hello Miga, Thank you for your reply. but my problem is, I already have Module to extract but I am not able to access my .Zip file. that is the main problem.

Comment: Then please tell us which module and show some code where you want to extract the file. Again, in https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.compression/blob/master/android/example/app.js you see an example extracting a file from the resource folder. Make sure to use app/assets/android/ the Resources/android/ is a folder that is created during compile-time

Comment: I have placed my .zip file in app/assets/android folder. so in apk its situated in assets/Resources folder.  so I am using var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, 'abc.zip');  to access the file from apk. but not able to access. did you get my Point ?

Comment: Yes, but you didn't mention all this in the question which makes it difficult to help. Does console.log(file.exists()) show 'true' ? Also try "ti clean" and compile it again